# Chaining table functions together

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Let's say I want to perform a SQL statement broken down into simple 'steps' as it might be done in an ETL. Here would be the most basic example:

```
-- step1
SELECT * FROM Sales JOIN Other WHERE Country='US'

-- step2 
SELECT * FROM NewTable Join (SELECT id, age FROM <previous1> GROUP BY Id) x USING (id)

-- step3
SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE someField in (SELECT field FROM <previous2>)

-- and 10 more steps...
```

I suppose one way I might do this 'step' concept is with the following:

```
WITH first_step AS (
        SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Country='US'),
     second_step AS (
        SELECT * FROM NewTable JOIN (SELECT id, age FROM first_step GROUP BY Id) x USING (id)),
     third_step AS (
        SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE someField in (SELECT field FROM second_step)),
    ...
```

This seems a much more readable and extensible approach than just throwing everything into a query, which I know from experience, becomes almost impossible to maintain or even understand after a certain number of steps:

```
SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE someField in (SELECT field FROM (
    SELECT * FROM NewTable Join (SELECT id, age FROM (
        SELECT * FROM Sales JOIN Other WHERE Country='US'
    ) GROUP BY Id) x USING (id)
)
```

Is that the best option here? Or how might this be best-organized without materializing intermediary results to a table (which might take a while to do if there's a lot of data between steps)?

Comment: *Ignore that this is a trivial example that can be done in a single query* - as a principle, every two queries related in the described way may be replaced with a single one, regardless of the degree of complexity. And this Is the best option.

Comment: @klin updated question. Imagine there are ten steps and I'd rather not having a query with ten levels of nesting and tons of code redundancy and would rather keep it easier to read and maintain.

Comment: I see, sometimes it is necessary to sacrifice some performance to improve the readability of the code and/or make it easier to maintain. However, the question seems too broad. In general, there is nothing wrong with using derived tables (personally preferred by me) or a cascaded list of queries in a common table expression, or even a combined manner. The choice depends on particulars.

Comment: Indeed, CTEs increase readability of queries, and also allow subsequent queries to access all previous ones. For example, step4 can join step1, step2, and step3, something you wouldn't be able to do without CTEs. Also, starting with PostgreSQL 12, now the engine does not always materialize each subquery; if the filtering can be pushed down (made early) the engine actually rewrites the query for you internally; this adds performance to the query with no effort on your part.

Comment: If CTEs are more readable to you, use them (but make sure you are running v12 or better). It is only a matter of taste.